# Can you change an IN parameter inside of a plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can you change a parameter that is set in the function header to something else with inside the function itself? The way I am reading this article it would seem like you can't [postgres tutorial link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this one myself.

The short answer is Yes. You can change the default `IN` parameters in a plpgsql function.

Please see the following example:

```
--CREATE SCHEMA it
CREATE FUNCTION it.foo (_animal TEXT ) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF _animal = 'cow' THEN
        _animal = 'steak';
    END IF;
    RETURN _animal;
END;
$$;

SELECT it.foo('cow');
```

Comment: It is a matter of scope. If you don't use an hard-coded string `'cow'` but a variable, it's value will not be updated to `'steak'` in the calling function.

Comment: --Are you sure
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION it.foo (_animal TEXT, _var text) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF _animal = _var THEN
        _animal = 'steak';
    END IF;
    RETURN _animal;
END;
$$;
SELECT it.foo('cow','cow');
--this still yields `steak`. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: try `DO
$$ DECLARE 
 src TEXT := 'cow';
 res TEXT;
 
 BEGIN
SELECT foo(src) INTO res;

raise notice '% - %',src,res;
END $$;

` and note that `src` is not updated

Comment: :-) back to 1st comment: it is a matter of scope. How do you define what is the parameter? What is sent to the function or what is received by the function? You are actually changing a copy of the parameter, not the parameter itself. It doesn't matter within the function but it has major impacts in code calling this function.